# Running SAS 9.4 from a flash drive

Tags: installation, sas, windows-10, usb-flash-drive

I have downloaded the SAS 9.4 suite on a flash drive. However, I do not have enough space on my hard disk to install SAS on my laptop.

Is there a way I can run SAS from my flash drive, instead of installing it on my laptop?

Operating system : Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Sort of? I have an external drive I've formatted (SSD/Flash) with an entire OS on it including SAS.

So I have VMware installed on my computer and it accesses the image file stored on the flash drive/SSD to run. You may even be able to do this with SAS UE. But you can also just use Academics on Demand which is cloud-based, assuming it's non-commercial usage and for learning.

EDIT: It's on a (256GB) flash drive that I keep on my computer because I don't really use the SD slot for anything else. It has Windows 10 on it because my main machine is a MacBook.

Comment: This is going to be the most reliable option. Installing to an image saved on a large flash drive or SSD will guarantee it will work. You can even add a portable version of VMWare to make it entirely self-contained. Installing SAS in the open on a flash drive will likely fail or be extremely difficult.